# How can I view all the %TODO comments I have marked using Kile?

Tags: editors, kile, todonotes

In my document I am leaving `%TODO` comments in order to get back at them at some time. How can I generate a list of them with their relevant information in Kile 2.0?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To precise Andrey's answer:

The [`todonotes` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/todonotes/) allows to use `\todo` commands to leave TODO notes in your documents. They are then displayed in the margin in draft mode, and removed in final mode. You can also generate a dynamic list of TODO notes with `\listoftodos`.

Comment: an alternative would be the [`fixme` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fixme/)

Answer (score 7):

Actually, Kile directly supports %TODO, %FIXME, and %TEST comments. There may be others, but none of them seem to be documented anymore.

Enter one of these and you will notice the syntax highlighting. To see all such comments in your TeX file or project look under the Structure tab in the side panel. You should see a tree of Sections, Figures, etc. with your todos and fixes at the top.

Comment: Excellent. This still works and should be more documented.

Comment: Checking in Kile 2.9.93, at least the following ones are syntax-highlighted: %TODO, %FIXME, %BUG, %NOTE, %HACK, %WARNING. However, only TODO and FIXME are listed in the Structure tab.   
I wonder if the highlighted words are listed in a configuration file somewhere.

Comment: You can add %TEST to that list

Comment: I've done some more digging. It seems that the "syntax alerts" supported in Kile are the same as in the Kate editor. They are listed here: https://kate-editor.org/syntax/data/html/test-alerts.html

The words are as follows. All of them are highlighted in Kile as of 2.9.93:
ALERT  ATTENTION  DANGER  HACK  SECURITY  BUG  FIXME  DEPRECATED  TASK  TODO  TBD  WARNING  CAUTION  NOLINT  ###  NOTE  NOTICE  TEST  TESTING

Answer (score 5):

A more low-level solution would be to use some `grep` magic. If your `%TODO` notes are all only one line long, then this would be as simple as running the following in your terminal:

```
grep -n '%TODO' file.tex
```

This would print out a list of the lines in `file.tex` including the pattern `%TODO`. The `-n` switch prints line numbers, making it easy to find the relevant lines.

If you have some multi-line `%TODO`s, then you can use the `-A 5` switch to print 5 lines after each instance of `%TODO`:

```
grep -n -A 5 '%TODO' file.tex
```

Indeed, with a multi-file project, you can search for all `%TODO`s across multiple files by replacing `file.tex` with `*.tex` or some other suitable wildcard.

Oh, here's something cool you could do, you could write the `%TODO` list to a file, and then `verbatiminput` the file into your tex document.

```
grep -n '%TODO' file.tex > todo.tex
```

And then add:

```
\verbatiminput{todo.tex}
```

To the end of your main file. This requires the verbatim package. Presumably `listings` has its own way of doing this.

You could even strip out the `%TODO` part of each line of `todo.tex` and write it as an item into an itemize environment. This is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you should start leaving [`\todo`](http://ctan.org/pkg/todo)s instead!